# Chrome Extension: Close tab that opened an external program before

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I'm currently writing a Chrome extension which has a context menu entry and when you click on it, Chrome opens a new tab whose address uses a different protocol. (Mine e.g. is called cmdown:// )

Anyway, the problem is that I can't get these tabs to close after loading and opening the program to handle the protocol.

My background.js:

```
    chrome.contextMenus.removeAll();
    var name1 = localStorage["name1"];
    var name2 = localStorage["name2"];
    var name3 = localStorage["name3"];
    var path1 = localStorage["path1"];
    var path2 = localStorage["path2"];
    var path3 = localStorage["path3"];
    var menuids = [];

    function downloadImage(info, tab) {
        for(var i = 0; i < menuids.length; i++) {
            if(menuids[i] == info.menuItemId) {
                switch(i) {
                    case 0:
                    chrome.tabs.create({"url":"cmdown://"+info.srcUrl+";"+path1,"active":false}, function(tab){
                            //Close tab here
                        });
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"cmdown://"+info.srcUrl+";"+path2,"active":false}, function(tab){
                            //Close tab here
                        });
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        chrome.tabs.create({"url":"cmdown://"+info.srcUrl+";"+path3,"active":false}, function(tab){
                            //Close tab here
                        });
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

if(typeof name1 != "undefined" && typeof path1 != "undefined") menuids[0] = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": name1, "contexts":["image"],
                                       "onclick": downloadImage});
if(typeof name2 != "undefined" && typeof path2 != "undefined") menuids[1] = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": name2, "contexts":["image"],
                                       "onclick": downloadImage});
if(typeof name3 != "undefined" && typeof path3 != "undefined") menuids[2] = chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": name3, "contexts":["image"],
                                       "onclick": downloadImage});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *chrome.tabs.query()* to get the tab, then close it with *chrome.tabs.remove()*

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html

Comment: I tried that but I read that the "url" parameter of queryInfo doesn't work when using custom protocols.
[Look at the last one](http://puu.sh/4h94G.png)